# GLSL Unsigned Int Values Not Retrieved Properly

Tags: c++, glsl

I have packed several values needed for shading a particular vertex into a single 32-bit uint. In the shader, it is unpacked like this:

```
vec3 color;
uint vertexData = data;
float sunlight, artificialLight;
bool occlusion;

artificialLight = float(vertexData & 31u);
vertexData = vertexData >> 5;
sunlight = float(vertexData & 31u);
vertexData = vertexData >> 5;
occlusion = bool(vertexData & 1u);
vertexData = vertexData >> 1;
color.b = float(vertexData & 127u);
vertexData = vertexData >> 7;
color.g = float(vertexData & 127u);
vertexData = vertexData >> 7;
color.r = float(vertexData & 127u);
```

The color produced by this extraction is much different from the originally intended color. For example:

```
130, 245, 90 --> 78, 125, 249   (These values are not exact)
```

I took the code and put it into my main c++ program and ran it with a debugger. It showed the right values.

```
130, 245, 90 --> 130, 245, 90
```

**EDIT**

I have taken a uint produced by my compressor and directly inputted it into my shader like this

```
vertexData = 2179293184;
```

Every vertex is shaded with the color of green this value corresponds to. So apparently, there is something going wrong with the transmission of the values. What might be causing this?

Comment: Maybe a problem of glsl float precision?

Comment: I don't think it is, because I am performing all the bit shifting and bitwise logic with unsigned integers, then converting it to a float after I have done that.

Comment: Have you checked if the endianness/byte order changes anything?

Comment: Hm, it might. How would I test this?

Comment: I have tried swapping the endianness in the shader, but this still results in similar graphical glitches. Is there any way to output a value from a shader into a console?

Comment: Are you using `glVertexAttribIPointer` to when setting up this vertex attribute (not `glVertexAttribPointer`)?

Comment: Thank you! I will test this as soon as possible. I think I used glVertexAttribPointer. I did not know about variations of this before. Could you make an answer from your comment so I can approve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your vertex data is being converted to float (and back again).

You should use `glVertexAttribIPointer` to upload integer vertex data without converting to floating point. From the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml):

> For glVertexAttribPointer, if normalized is set to GL_TRUE, it
>   indicates that values stored in an integer format are to be mapped to
>   the range [-1,1] (for signed values) or [0,1] (for unsigned values)
>   when they are accessed and converted to floating point. Otherwise,
>   values will be converted to floats directly without normalization.
>
> For glVertexAttribIPointer, only the integer types GL_BYTE,
>   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_SHORT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_INT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT
>   are accepted. Values are always left as integer values.

Comment: I can't tell you how long I suffered trying to figure out why my bit shifting was not working in a shader, and the solution was simply using the proper function. I naively thought that `glVertexAttribPointer` was appropriate for integers as well. This has saved me so much trouble, thank you, even if the answer is old.